# divide an array into many arrays using a given key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have an array like

```
array (
  (1) => array => ([1]=aa, [2]=other keys and values),
  (2) => array => ([1]=bb, [2]=other keys and values),
  (3) => array => ([1]=cc, [2]=other keys and values),
  (4) => array => ([1]=aa, [2]=other keys and values),
  (5) => array => ([1]=bb, [2]=other keys and values),
  (6) => array => ([1]=cc, [2]=other keys and values),
  (7) => array => ([1]=bb, [2]=other keys and values)
)
```

I would like to make arrays based on `[1] = aa/bb/cc/dd`.

To divide the original array in to various unique arrays which have same value of `[1]` key.

I do not want to use foreach as the result set is expected to reach 10k rows.

Is this optimal at all??

Comment: You do not want to use `foreach`? What else would you like to use? Magic? ;-P

Answer (score 2):

No matter what solution you choose, you **will have to** loop over all of the rows in your array, no matter what. Either directly or indirectly. There is no magic code that can decide what's inside a sealed box without opening the box.

So, apart from the obvious `foreach` you can use [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this optimal at all??

Definitely not.

Though it is not foreach to blame but a programmer who have 10k rows to loop over.

If it's regular web-page served on user's request, there shouldn't be 10k rows by any means. You have to reduce the number at least by factor of 100. Or let the data storage to do the necessary calculations.